# Why is a URL not returned when using the pathto(document) helper function?

Tags: python-sphinx

According to the Sphinx docs on templating, [pathto(document)](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/templating.html#pathto) returns the path to a Sphinx document as a URL." By definition, a URL typically includes the scheme, the host, and the path component. So, why does `pathto(root_doc)` return `index.html` instead of, for example, `https://example.com/index.html`? `index.html` is not a URL.  Can someone enlighten me? What is the best way to get an absolute URL for a document in Sphinx?

Comment: Perhaps the setting of [`html_baseurl`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_baseurl) is what you want? I assume without setting that value, the default is `''`, which omits the protocol and host.

Comment: Given more context, thanks to @StevePiercy, I can see much better how this works. Thanks, Steve!

Comment: I added an answer. If it is correct, would you please accept it by clicking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the setting [`html_baseurl`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_baseurl). Without setting that value, the default is '', which omits the protocol and host.